# Twitter API Python Search -- Error 32 'Could not authenticate you'

Tags: python, api, twitter, oauth

I've seen posts about how to address this in PHP, but I couldn't figure out how to translate them into Python.

I'm trying to pull some twitter data with

```
import json
import os
import twitter

    twitter_k = twitter.Api(consumer_key='key',
                  consumer_secret='key',
                  access_token_key='key',
                  access_token_secret='key')

url='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=&geocode=-39.938395,-100.476275,3750km&lang=en&until:2017-02-27&since:2017-2-25'

tweets = requests.get(url, twitter_k)

j=tweets.json()

save_path='path'
name_of_file='tweets'

completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")

with open(completeName, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(j, outfile)
```

Slight variations of this have yielded "215 "Bad Authentication data""

I've regenerated my keys, and it still doesn't work.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: There are python twitter libraries. You don't need to use requests.

Comment: I had similar problems with python-twitter.

Do you have a twitter library you recommend? I need to be able to search by geo and date.

Comment: Anything after `q=` is just a query string. Geo shouldn't matter. I was just asking if you tried them

Comment: I'm using both `twitter` and `tweepy` they work the same. Have you tried anything other command?